# C# 4.0: dynamic 'this' pointer

Tags: c#, dynamic, c#-4.0

Is it possible to allow methods and properties of the 'this' pointer to be resolved dynamically?

Put another way, can a class have a dynamic superclass?

**Clarification**

I would like to be able to subclass some class and access properties and methods that aren't defined at compile-time.

```
class MyClass : DynamicObject
{
    public void ReceiveValue(object value) {
        MyProperty = value;
    }
}
```

`DynamicObject` provides a way for my code to get notified that `set_MyProperty` has been called with the argument `value` above, correct? I know this is possible if you use a syntax like:

```
var mc = new MyClass();
...
dynamic dmc = mc;
dmc.MyProperty = value;
```

But I want to be able to do this from within the methods of MyClass, almost as if I had done:

```
dynamic dmc = this;
dmc.MyProperty = value;
```

Does `DynamicObject` have me covered?

Comment: are you implying the ability for a class to choose its parent at runtime, instead of compile time ?

Comment: How could 'this' ever be dynamic? You're defining 'this' in your own class.

Comment: You can always do `(dynamic)this`, of course, and you can wrap that in a private property if you really want to. If that's not quite what you want, then please explain it more precisely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't have a dynamic base class. Aside from anything else, the system still needs to know how much space to allocate when you create a new instance of your class.

Could you explain what you're trying to achieve? There may well be ways in which `dynamic` would help without needing quite this behaviour.

EDIT: Okay, having seen your edit - I don't think you can quite do what you want, but if you just use the

```
dynamic dmc = this;
dmc.MyProperty = value;
```

or

```
((dynamic)this).MyProperty = value;
```

workaround it should be fine. To put it another way: the `this` reference is always statically typed, but you can have an expression with the *value* of `this` but with a dynamic type.

That shouldn't be too onerous unless you're doing a *lot* of dynamic work - in which case I'd recommend that you use a fully dynamic language instead. If you implement the bulk of your dynamic code in IronPython/IronRuby, you can easily integrate it with your C# code anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Doing something fully dynamic is an interesting idea; unfortunately last time I tested the DLR (v0.91, specifically the hosting API if I recall correctly) leaked memory, and my application is a long-running process.

Comment: I suspect that things are a lot further on now than they used to be :) Note that if you use `dynamic` *at all* in your C# code, you're already using the DLR.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basis of polymorphism.  The method/property called will be the one given lowest in the heirarchy of the objects type.

Comment: I mean resolving the property or method at runtime via C# 4.0 dynamic call site binding.

Comment: If I understand bvanderveen correctly he is asking about doing the opposite of polymorphism or at least in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    class B
    {
        public void M(object o)
        {
            dynamic i = this;
            i.P = o;
        }
    }

    class D : B
    {
        public object P { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var d = new D();
            d.M(1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a tangent, but [there are languages](http://bracha.org/newspeak-modules.pdf) where *every* class's superclass is dynamic - i.e. where class name resolution is virtual and override-able.