# Making "this" implicitly dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, c#-4.0

I have a class that inherits from *DynamicObject* and overrides some of its members. I was wondering if there is any tricks that I could use that made 'this' implicitly dynamic (or at least the appearance of), so that when I want to dynamically add members inside the class I wouldn't have to do

```
((dynamic)this).Whatever = 10;
```

It would be much nicer if I could do

```
Whatever = 10;
```

I am just spiking some stuff so I can't add any real context to this and no, Ruby isn't the solution this time ;)

I could wrap it in a property but it would add to the API of the functionality since I would have to do

```
Property.Whatever = 10;
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502276/c-4-0-dynamic-this-pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just extend the baseclass ?

```
public class DynamicObjectEx : DynamicObject
{
    protected dynamic self
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could simply switch to VB.NET with option strict off or whatever the setting is ;-)

Comment: Nevermind.. I read your code as an override of a self property on DynamicObject which isn't the case. Yeah this is the same solution I said with Property.Whatever

Answer (score 1):

**It's not possible.** Your approach with the `Property.Whatever` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to just add them as non-dynamic attributes? If you're using "this" within your class, you're sure that those attributes will already have to be there, no?

I don't know much about dynamic classes though so correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Actually no. This is a base class and I want to dynamically add members to inheritors of the class and then inspect implementors at runtime if they provide specific methods. I know it sounds nuts but there is a point + it is only a proof of concept spike :)